# What is stopping browser to download pdf file

Tags: spring-boot, response-headers

I am using `spring boot` application to download a `jasper file`, which is downloaded in my system, on browser. The code that I have written is:

```
@GetMapping("/download")
    public ResponseEntity downloadFileFromLocal(HttpServletResponse response) throws JRException, SQLException, IOException {
        
        
        Path path = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home") + "//downloads//" + "fileName.pdf");
        Resource resource = null;
        try {
            resource = new UrlResource(path.toUri());
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/download"))
                .header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" +  resource.getFilename() + "\"")
                .body(resource);
    }
```

This code is `working perfectly fine` and my file is being downloaded on browser when I try this code in a simple application i.e. practice approach. However, when I try to download the file in my `main application` with the `same code` then nothing happens. I am not sure what is stopping browser to download my pdf file in browser. The expected result is:

[image]

I think there is some problem with the `response Headers`.

Following is the `response header` for my `Practice application` file:

```
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="Daily%20Report%20For%20Site_ID%201.pdf"
Content-Length: 2869
Content-Type: application/download
Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 10:48:24 GMT
Keep-Alive: timeout=60
```

And for `main application`, `response headers` are:

```
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 27 Dec 2021 11:28:33 GMT
Expires: 0
Pragma: no-cache
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
```

Comment: Looks like you are using wrong expression

Comment: @AlexK In key field?? It does not give me any other options other than those for which I have wrote query. For example I have written `select Sum(desktop_devices_count) as Desktop_Device,Sum(mobile_devices_count) as Mobile_Device,Sum(tablet_devices_count) as Tablet_Device from convertopia.search_analytic_history where search_analytic_id='1';
`
And therefore, it only allows me to write any one of $F{Desktop_device}, $F{Mobile_device} or $F{Tablet_device}

Comment: Looks like you should start from learning how to work with JasperReports. [The JasperReports Ultimate Guide](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/JasperReports-Ultimate-Guide-3.pdf)